# Patch Decorator - side effect with no parameter to function

Tags: python, python-2.7, patch

I want to decorate my test to patch specific function. I'm not interested in getting the mock object as a parameter to the function.
In this example, I want to be able to omit `mock_my_foo` parameter:

```
def my_foo(self):
    print "My side_effect"

class SampleTest(TestCase):
   @patch('some_module.foo', side_effect=my_foo)
   def test_something(self, mock_my_foo):
      pass
```

I'm using python 2.7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to do it with specifying the `new` param of patch and assigning it a mock object that had the side_effect already set:

```
def my_foo(self):
    print "My side_effect"

class SampleTest(TestCase):
    @patch('some_module.foo', new=Mock(side_effect=my_foo))
    def test_something(self):
        pass
```